# How do I default my css class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a side panel which opens with a click event.
The panel slides from the right and goes to the left when I close it, but it should start again from the right. Now when I click the icon the second time it re-starts from the left side, any help would be appreciated.

So let's say I click the icon:
- the panel opens from the right side of the screen
When I close the panel
- panel closes and moves towards the left side of the screen
Then when I click the icon again
- panel opens from left side instead of the right side

HTML:

```
<div class="open-slide from-right">
    <a href="#0" class="close"></a>
    <div class="open-slide-container"></div>
</div>
<div class="open-btn">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign">
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    //open the lateral panel
    $('.open-btn').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.open-slide').toggleClass('is-visible');
    });
    //close the lateral panel
    $('.open-slide').on('click', function(event) {
        if ($(event.target).is('.open-slide-close')) {
            $('.open-slide').removeClass('is-visible');
            // to close the panel from left
            $('.open-slide').toggleClass('from-left');

            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.open-slide {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0.6s;
    -moz-transition: visibility 0s 0.6s;
    transition: visibility 0s 0.6s;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    z-index: 9;
}
.open-slide::after {
    /* overlay layer */

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: background 0.3s 0.3s;
    transition: background 0.3s 0.3s;
}
.open-slide.is-visible {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0s;
    -moz-transition: visibility 0s 0s;
    transition: visibility 0s 0s;
}
.open-slide.is-visible::after {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s 0s;
    -moz-transition: background 0.3s 0s;
    transition: background 0.3s 0s;
}
.open-slide.is-visible .open-slide-close::before {
    -webkit-animation: cd-close-1 0.6s 0.3s;
    -moz-animation: cd-close-1 0.6s 0.3s;
    animation: cd-close-1 0.6s 0.3s;
}
.open-slide.is-visible .open-slide-close::after {
    -webkit-animation: cd-close-2 0.6s 0.3s;
    -moz-animation: cd-close-2 0.6s 0.3s;
    animation: cd-close-2 0.6s 0.3s;
}
.from-right .open-slide-container {
    right: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}
.from-left .open-slide-container {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}
.is-visible .open-slide-container {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
```

Comment: Well, given that your HTML is invalid and your JQuery refers to CSS that you didn't post, we're not going to be able to help you much.

Comment: @ScottMarcus thanks for your message, I added the CSS and more details as requested.

Comment: Your HTML is still invalid. You are missing: `</i>`

Comment: Your HTML code is missing </i>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you didn't provide enough info for your question. Try this:

```js
        jQuery(function($) {
        //open the lateral panel
        $('.open-btn').on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('.open-slide').toggleClass('is-visible');
        });
        //close the lateral panel
        $('.open-slide').on('click', function(event) {
            if ($(event.target).is('.close')) {
                $('.open-slide').removeClass('is-visible');
                // to close the panel from left
                $('.open-slide').toggleClass('from-right');
    
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I want it to close from left, but when I click the icon again I want it open from the right side only. So the panel should always open from the right and close from the left. @abiudo orinar

Comment: If there's not enough info, why are you even answering?